# What's difference Task.Run() , Calling async void AAA() on Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, task

As far as I know, there are three ways to call async method. (I'm sure there are much more)

- 1> `Task.Run(async () = {...}).`
- 2> Just calling `AAA();`

and AAA should be looks like

```
async void AAA()
{
...
}
```

- 3> `Device.InvokeMainThread(async () => {...});`

I know If I use option 1(`Task.run`) process will go on background thread and option 3 is not.

What about option 2? It's on main thread if I called from `OnAppearing()`?
First of all, Is there not any problem to use like that?

And option2 and 3 are same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Executes `AAA` on a thread pool thread.
2. Executes `AAA` on the calling thread.
3. Executes `AAA` on the main thread.

As an aside, you should [avoid async void methods](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/).

Comment: Thanks so much. It's really helpful.